# Nodejs encode string ISO8859-1

Tags: node.js

I've been looking for an answer for some days.

I am receiving data per post from a form containing special characters (accents)

eg      : Está é uma sala de teste
App Node: Est%E1+%E9+uma+sala+de+teste

What is the correct way in nodejs, to decode the string to save to in my database?

I did it that way. But I'm sure it's not the right way

[decode string with accents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znqv2.jpg)

My apologize if this is a duplicate issue, but not that I found myself able to resolve the issue

thank you any advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module like [`iconv-urlencode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-urlencode) for that:

```
const conv = require('iconv-urlencode');
let input  = 'Est%E1+%E9+uma+sala+de+teste';

console.log( conv.decode(input, 'latin-1') );
// Está é uma sala de teste
```